# Invalid parameter information was passed to method 'differential.parsecommitmessage'

Tags: arcanist

It show me an error:

```
ERR-CONDUIT-CORE: Invalid parameter information was passed to method `differential.parsecommitmessage`.
(Run with `--trace` for a full exception trace.)
```

When I type `arc diff` in CMD. I use `arcanist` and `php` to review my code, and the tools required on my computer is the lasted. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- make sure your commit file is UTF-8.
- check your input words,do not contains special character.

Comment: My CVS is hg, whose default encoding is GBK and it can't be decoded by `arcanist`.

Answer (score 0):

make your filepath in english, I fixed it by remove my chinese word